# Run task if the immediate parent is either in Success or Failed states only

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

I have a DAG and it has a task X somewhere in the middle which can fail but I don't want the DAG to get blocked because of this task. I want the DAG to behave as if task X succeeded even if it has failed.

I was thinking of adding some trigger rule to downstream of task X but I don't think there's a trigger rule for success or failure only.

I am aware of a hacky solution using ShortCircuitOperator.

I don't think `soft_fail` is available for non-sensor tasks.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

I am using Airflow 2.2

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `trigger_rule='all_done'` or `trigger_rule='none_skipped'` in the downstream task after `x`.
The main difference depends how you want to treat the `skipped` state.
`trigger_rule='all_done'` -> if `x` is skipped then downstream will run
`trigger_rule='none_skipped'` -> if `x` is skipped then downstream will not run.

Example:

```
from datetime import datetime

from airflow import DAG, AirflowException
from airflow.decorators import task
from airflow.operators.empty import EmptyOperator

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': datetime(2023, 4, 1)
}

with DAG('example_stackoverflow', schedule=None, default_args=default_args):
    a = EmptyOperator(task_id='a')

    @task()
    def x():
        return

    y = EmptyOperator(task_id='y', trigger_rule='all_done')
    z = EmptyOperator(task_id='z')

    a >> x() >> y >> z
```

[image]

If changing task `x` code to:

```
@task()
def x():
    raise AirflowException()
```

[image]

If changing task `x` code to:

```
@task()
def x():
    raise AirflowSkipException()
```

[image]

Comment: Let's say the DAG looks like `a->b->c->x->y->z`. If we use `all_done` and say `a` or `b` fail then `c` and `x` will go into `upstream_failed` state and `y` will get triggered. This violates my requirement of the immediate parent being in success/failure only.

Comment: So basically you don't care about the parent task state. You want to always execute the downstream task, then why not using `always` trigger rule?

Comment: No, I care about a, b, c, y, and z states - they must be successful. I don't care whether x is in failed or successful state.
In other words, I want the DAG to go into failed state if a, b, c, y and z are in any state other than successful and x can be either successful or failed.

Comment: This is a very odd use case. For what you are describing I suggest to write a leaf task that will check the statuses of upstream tasks and decide how to finish the DAG. For a larger context, I would suggest to review if the DAG is constructed right. This just feels more like 2 separated DAGs